# Why threads doesn't work properly when used with class method

Tags: python, multithreading, class

I have this code:

```
import threading
import time
import random 

buyers_names = [("Jo","Vi"), ("Jok", "Ser"), ("Jur", "Sau")]

class Buyer():
    """Buyer"""
    def __init__(self, first_name = None,last_name= None):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
    def buy(self):
        print("Buyer {0} {1}: starts to look for tickets".format(self.first_name, self.last_name))
        wondering = random.randint(2,10)
        print("Time that will take is {0}".format(wondering))
        time.sleep(wondering)
        print("Buyer {0} {1}: finishes to look for tickets".format(self.first_name, self.last_name))
        return

# Buyers list  
buyers = [Buyer(names[0], names[1]) for names in buyers_names]

for buyer in buyers:    
    buy = threading.Thread(target=buyer.buy())   
    buy.start()
```

and I have this output:

[image]

It behaves as a regular loop that waits for method to do it's thing.

I checked similar code as separate function and it works as threads should work. Starts everything in the loop and return whenever functions finishes.

Why the code that I posted waiting for method to finish instead initiating all the objects and then waiting for methods to finish?

Comment: `target=buyer.buy()` is a typo.

Comment: Should be `buy = threading.Thread(target=buyer.buy)`

Comment: You are calling the function instead of passing it to the thread